# How you build a project using gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My build.gradle is given below.i have found this error.

```
Error:(15) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'smartwisher'.
> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_3rvo44ss7197kfip29gkh81rb6$_run_closure2@1d7a1869] on root project 'smartwisher'.
```

This is build.gradle which i have in my android studio.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
        defaultConfig {}
        productFlavors {
        }
    }
    dependencies {
    }
```

Comment: what gradle version are you using?

Comment: not that, latest is 1.12, i use 1.10. 1.11 gave me some errors. check th folder where gradle is installed for the version number

Comment: Oh,sorry i am using 1.12

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the **top level** `build.gradle` to specify android configuration.

You have to move the android block in your `module/build.gradle file.`

Your folders.

```
root
  module
     build.gradle
  build.gradle
  settings.gradle
```

**In your top-level file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**In your module/build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {

}

dependencies {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your file is not easy to read here, you should put it in a code block.
For what I saw you are missing at least one line :

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```

Comment: now i am getting fileNotFound exception.
Error:Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\smartwisher\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
D:\smartwisher\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify pluging applying in `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
```